# View groups inside of groups with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, nested-groups

I am trying to see which groups are inside of a group. For example:
`ACCCLK_JC` is the job code for `ACCCLK`. It contains roughly 17 groups. I wish to see each group inside this group. This is also known as nested groups or subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

While typing this question out I discovered the answer.

```
 Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
```

Comment: A shorter way is to pipe to a ForEach loop and only specify the property to expand, such as `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $Group | % Name`